# Install GApps onto HTC One w/ CyanogenMod 10.2 + ClockworkMod Recovery 6.0.4.3

Tags: cyanogenmod, clockworkmod-recovery, google-apps, htc-one

I'm currently trying to install the GApps onto my HTC One. I got CyanogenMod working using the installer app on the play store, but now I don't have any of the GApps. Help me? How can I install the GApps?

Answer (score 1):

[Download](http://goo.im/gapps) and copy the GAPPS zip file to your SD card.

Reboot your phone into CWM recovery mode. To do this, turn phone off, and press Volume Up + Home + Power button together. Your phone would then startup into recovery mode.

Select `install zip`. Look for the gapps file via `choose zip from /sdcard` if it's in the internal sd card, or `choose zip from /storage/sdcard1` if it's in the external SD card.

After you flash it, reboot your phone (it's in one of the options).

Comment: Ensure you have the correct version of GApps also, the 4.4 ones do not work in 4.3 and so on! XDA has a good list of them, and the 'Paranoid Android' ROM maintains every version of GApps very well on their server (they'll work on Cyanogenmod).